# How to append or change metadata from controller?

Tags: blocks, magento-1, controllers, meta

How to change meta data(robots meta tag) from controller in Magento ? **Is there a way to access head block from controller and append new value in it ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes definitely you can use the following code in your controller action method:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('My Custom Meta Title'));
```

You just need to ensure that this code is called after `$this->loadLayout();` and before `$this->renderLayout();`

Extra methods:

- `setDescription` to set the meta description
- `setKeywords` to set the meta keywords

Comment: can i use this anywhere in magento?

Comment: @miso911 no only in controllers

Comment: setDescription is working but when i add this $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addItem('link_rel', $prevUrl, 'rel="prev"'); on first page is working well but on 2, 3 , 4 .. is not working.